# Error setting up logging on Key vault Log category 'AuditEvents' is not available

Tags: azure, logging, azure-keyvault

Can someone please help me with the following quick question.

I have set up a Premium Key Vault
I have setup a storage account (Standard_LRS)

I am now trying to enable logging for my key vault (following a section of the following https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/key-vault-logging )

After getting my Key Vault and Storage Account into variables I try the following PowerShell command

```
Set-AzureRmDiagnosticSetting -ResourceId $kv.ResourceId 
    -StorageAccountId $sa.Id -Enabled $true -Categories AuditEvent
```

However when I run the above command I get the following error

> Set-AzureRmDiagnosticSetting : **Log category 'AuditEvents' is not
>   available** At line:1 char:1
>   + Set-AzureRmDiagnosticSetting -ResourceId $kv.ResourceId -StorageAccou ...
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : CloseError: (:) [Set-AzureRmDiagnosticSetting], ArgumentException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Insights.Diagnostics.SetAzureRmDiagnosticSettingCommand

Any ideas please

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is still valid, but i ran in to this, and noticed the category 'AuditEvent' is changed to 'Audit' whan changing this, everything works as predicted.

Answer (score 0):

Additional vendor support on this known issue can be found and the workaround below.

If you receive this error, update your deployments to replace any metric category names with AllMetrics to fix the issue.

If the deployment was previously adding multiple categories, only keep one with the AllMetrics reference. If you continue to have the problem, contact Azure support through the Azure portal.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/essentials/diagnostic-settings?tabs=portal#metric-category-isnt-supported